# Make nodejs request image to external site and send back to front end

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using nodejs with a server.
I need to do a backend request in an url to get an jpg, png... image and send the response to my angular frontend.

I have tried the next but it doesn´t work.
When I do test using Postman. Only text is showing in the screen. No image.

What am I doing wrong?

//node

```
var request=require('request');
app.get('/foto', function(req, res, next) {
            request.get('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ortototem.appspot.com/o/Photos%2F51%2FFoto?alt=media&token=XXXXX',
                function(err,resp,body){
              if(err) {
                next(err)
              }else{ 
                 if(resp.statusCode !== 200 ) {
                    console.log(resp)
                 } else res.send(resp)
              }
        })
```

Comment: What is the text that shows instead of the image?  Can you post it?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want the backend to fetch the image from an external url, and not your frontend directly?

Comment: Also postman wouldn’t know that an image is being returned because your endpoint does not have an extension. It would spit out the raw data for the image.  Even if it did have an extension, I’m not sure Postman can handle non-text responses

Comment: @RaphaMex  I am trying to use my backend node server as a proxy to get image from firebase. If I do it right from my frontend I get CORS orgin error.

Comment: @Xavier This is a url of a image in Firebase Storage

Comment: Shows something as "{"statusCode":200,"body":"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000ï¿½ï¿½\u0000ï¿½\u0000\t\u0006\u0007\u0012\u0012\u0012\u0015\u0013\u0013\u0012\u0015\u0016\u0015\u0015\u0017\u0015\u0015\u0018\u0017\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0015\u0018\u0016\u0018\u0018\u0018\u0016\u0018\u0018\u0017\u0015\u0017\u0018\u001d( \u0018\u001d%\u001d\u0017\u0015!1!%)+...\u0017\u001f383-7(-.+\u0001\n\n\n\u000e\r\u000e\u001b\u0010\u0010\u001a-\u001f\u001f%--+----------------------------+-----------------+ï¿½ï¿½\u0000\u"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your endpoint does not have an extension, you will have to set the `Content-Type` header on your response to match the mime type of the image you are getting.  Probably by programmatically detecting it from your google storage response or something. You will also need to be sure you are passing in and rendering binary data with a Buffer type.

For example:

```
request.get('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ortototem.appspot.com/o/Photos%2F51%2FFoto?alt=media&token=YOUR_TOKEN', { encoding: null }, function(err,resp) {
  if(err) {
    next(err)
  } else {
    if(resp.statusCode !== 200 ) {
      console.log(resp)
    } else {
      res.contentType(resp.headers['content-type']);
      res.end(resp.body, 'binary');
    }
  }
});
```

Without this Postman or any Browser won’t know that it’s an image or what type of image it is so it will assume it’s plain text.

The three important items here are:

1. Specify the `encoding: null` option on `request` so body is loaded as a Buffer
2. Set `res.contentType` equal to the content-type from Firebase response
3. Specify binary data in the express response with `res.end(resp.body, 'binary')`

Comment: Hi, it doesn´t work. Here is the correct url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ortototem.appspot.com/o/Photos%2F51%2FFoto?alt=media&token=bc891a7c-4b54-4b52-8276-4fec6f57d030      If you past into postmon the image is showing correctly

Comment: Hey @LuizAlves, I just updated my answer.  It's working with a mini express script on my machine.  Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Xavier. I was stuck with it. You save me.